# How to archive a build step in Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to temporarily hide or archive a build step in TeamCity? There is a way to pause them and hide them just for myself -- others will still see it -- but I didn't see any way to hide it from all users or archive them.

Comment: Do you mean a build configuration (part of a build project, e.g. release tests), or a build step (part of a build configuration, e.g. run MSBuild)? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16193963/1364007) has a screenshot making the distinction a bit clearer. From your description I think you are talking about a configuration. If so, the question above mentions setting up *roles* to do that very job.

Comment: It's not pretty, but you can 'move' the build step to a different project, one that has the name *archive*

Comment: I asked the wrong question... I'll ask the right one, too, this one also being useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable/enable a build step in teamcity . You can do this by going to the edit build configurations -> build steps -> hover over particular build step and click disable build step. You can this even if your build configuration is based of a template

[Teamcity wiki description](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Build+Steps)

You can not however hide/archive a build step.