# Allow/deny users from running a build configuration in Teamcity

Tags: permissions, teamcity, build-chain

I have a build chain of 4 build configurations, which correspond to different teams' tasks. The idea behind the configurations is this:

1. Run the build itself
2. Move build to staging
3. QA approved
4. Release

Each of those configurations have different responsible people. People not responsible for a given configuration should not be allowed to run it.

I know I can define roles on project-level, but here I need to define it on a build configuration-level. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: That´s not possible atm - refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193963/how-to-hide-teamcity-configuration-for-selected-users for possible work arrounds.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create subprojects for each configuration and then assign roles corresponding to restrictions.
2. You can add precondition step to each job where check username and fail step and job if user not allowed to run this job.

I made the second approach in similar case.